# Restarting emacs changes default font

Tags: init-file, fonts, customize

I'm new to Emacs. Been a vim user.

Using `M-x customize-face`, irrespective of what font I set it to, Emacs always ends up using `Inconsolata-g for Powerline` font. Default is `DejaVu Sans Mono`. I tried removing `.emacs.d` directory as well as emacs (package itself), but neither helps.

Here's what I do:

1. `M-x customize-face default`
2. Set it to, say, `Ubuntu Mono Regular`
3. Hit `Apply` and things look good
4. So I hit `State` and choose option `#1` which stores it to `~/.emacs` (for fresh install; I use `~/.emacs/init.el` instead - not sure which is better of two)
5. `C-x C-c`
6. Start emacs again and the font is set back to `Inconsolata-g for Powerline`

How do I get rid of what I'm seeing on step 6 here? I saved `~/.emacs` to `~/.emacs.d/init.el` and here are its contents:

```
$ cat .emacs.d/init.el 
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 130 :width normal :foundry "PfEd" :family "Ubuntu Mono Regular")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like [bug #25228](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25228): *GNU emacs 25.1: **custom-set-faces from init file ~/.emacs ignored***.

Take a look at that, and see if it doesn't correspond to your scenario.

Comment: Specifically see if `(define-key special-event-map [config-changed-event] 'ignore)` helps. https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25228#152

Comment: I think I was using incorrect font name all the time. Using correct name seems to solve the issue and persists the restarts. Thanks for your help Drew & npostavs

Comment: Then please do one of two things: (1) delete your question or (2) add the solution you found as an answer, and accept that answer. I'd suggest #1, as I doubt the question and answer will help someone else, but you decide. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(setq default-frame-alist '((font . "PragmataPro-13")))
```

"PragmataPro" is the font name, 13 is the font size, replace them with your own.